# redirect log files created in a docker container to stdout / stderr

Tags: docker, stdout, stderr

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
VOLUME ["/LOGS"]
COPY ./testServer .
ENTRYPOINT ./testServer 8600
```

"testServer" has log files that are being written to. They are located in the directory "LOGS". Each time "testServer" is started, a new log is created. What I wanted to do was to "tail" the latest log file in the directory to stdout / stderr.

I tried adding:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "tail $( ls -Art /LOGS | tail -n 1 ) > out_server.log 2>&1"]
```

to the Dockerfile (and rebuilt the image thereafter) but it did not work.

How can this be done?

TIA

Comment: Did you want the output to go to the file out_server.log or to stdout? When you say it didn't work, what did it do incorrectly?

Comment: you can use `docker exec container_name -c "tail -f /your/path/to/log"`

Comment: Have you tried `docker logs`?

Comment: Hi all and thanks for the response

Comment: @BMitch - I would like the output to go to stdout / stderr. I am using Portainer - it (Portainer) allows one to see stderr and stdout files for a running container. When I put the CMD (above) in the Dockerfile (and created a new image), when running it, Portainer did not show anything in the stderr/stdout displays.

Comment: @nick_gabpe I was hoping to redirect the output to the stdout/stderr of the container.

Comment: @Engineer Dollery  I have not but I can give it a look-see. Will this allow one to write to the stderr/stdout of the container?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead you using tail, you can symlink the log file to the container process's stdout. To do so, you need to wrap your executable in a separate script so it gets launched as a process separate from the container's main process.

Script to execute:

```
#!/bin/bash

# The application log will be redirected to the main docker container process's stdout, so # that it will show up in the container logs
touch /my/app/application.log
ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /my/app/application.log

# Execute my app
./testServer 8600
```

And in the docker file just copy and execute the script

```
COPY start_server.sh /the/above/script/start_server.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "/the/above/script/start_server.sh"]
```

Comment: I like this solution quite a lot. I was concerned about dealing with log rotation, but in an ephemeral container, I can get away with not worrying about it. The couple of small  addenda I'll throw in here are that I don't know why you're doing a touch of the file first, ln -sf should create it regardless. And also, I didn't bother with the wrapper script, just created the symlink inside the Dockerfile.

Comment: Most containers may have only one process running inside, but aren't we losing data written by other processes to stdout by this?

Comment: Same question as Ganapathi essentially. Won't this make it where the log file is stdout essentially, and either: prevent anything that would normally write to STDOUT from writing there, OR cause things trying to write to STDOUT to actually write to the log file?

Answer (score 8):

There are two issues here.

1. You have an `ENTRYPOINT` defined and you are trying to run a command with `CMD`. Docker starts a container with a single process, and when you define both, `CMD` is appended to `ENTRYPOINT` as additional cli args. What the container is running as pid 1 is:

   `/bin/sh -c './testServer 8600 /bin/sh -c "tail $( ls -Art /LOGS | tail -n 1 ) > out_server.log 2>&1"'`

   Unless testServer runs the extra args, they'll never get used.
2. If the command you were running did work, it would output everything to /out_server.log inside the container, not to stdout, and it would stop as soon as it reached the end of the input. If that's your pid 1, the container would also exit at that point.

To fix this, you can create an entrypoint.sh to be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

./testServer 8600 &
sleep 2 # give testServer time to create the newest log
exec tail -f $( ls -Art /LOGS | tail -n 1 )
```

That entrypoint starts up testServer in the background and then runs the tail with an exec. The exec replaces pid 1 so that signals are passed through.

Update your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# This apt-get line shouldn't be needed unless something else 
# needs the possibly outdated package repo list
# RUN apt-get update

# Removing this volume, you can create it from a docker-compose.yml
# VOLUME ["/LOGS"]

COPY entrypoint.sh testServer /
RUN chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh /testServer
ENTRYPOINT [ "/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

For more details on why I removed the `VOLUME` line, see [my blog post here](https://boxboat.com/2017/01/23/volumes-and-dockerfiles-dont-mix/).

Answer (score 5):

I found following useful.

```
#forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

As a result of above lines, content written to `access.log` and `error.log` will be written to `stdout` and `stderr` respectively.

[Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/599103/make-a-docker-application-write-to-stdout)

Answer (score -1):

If this is a requirement, I would reconfigure the syslog that ubuntu uses to output. An example is [here](https://github.com/jumanjihouse/docker-rsyslog/blob/master/src/etc/rsyslog.d/stdout.conf)

Comment: Thanks - I just wanted to redirect the contents of the log file (that the server is writing to) to the stdout/stderr of the container itself. The software Portainer displays the stderr/stdout of a running container.