# Redirect a customized application log in /var/log to stdout in Kubernetes?

Tags: logging, kubernetes, containers

I need help to **stdout** an application log.
I have a log file in /var/log as ad.log.
I need to print the ad.log in **stdout** so that I can see it from within `kubectl logs <podname>`

I tried options like:

```
ln -sf /proc/1/fd/1 /var/log/ad.log
ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/ad.log
```

but nothing helps. Please offer suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938648/redirect-log-files-created-in-a-docker-container-to-stdout-stderr

Comment: Does this answer your question? [redirect log files created in a docker container to stdout / stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938648/redirect-log-files-created-in-a-docker-container-to-stdout-stderr)

Comment: Please check the link provided above, for it's very similar to your question.