# pods logs in .txt file need topush these logs to cloudwatch

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pod

The pods have been successfully created and it is running but I am unable to get the logs from the pods. I even checked in Lens and 'kubectl logs pod' its not showing any logs. Logs are generated in .txt format and I can see these file inside the container. Could anyone please suggest me what can be done to obtain the logs? I have to send the same logs to Cloud watch. I have deployed FluentD too. I can see logs in cloud watch for only the pod which is in crash loop not other pods.

Comment: Can you redirect those txt files to stdout? Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55444469/redirecting-script-output-to-docker-logs or also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938648/redirect-log-files-created-in-a-docker-container-to-stdout-stderr

Comment: yes, best to log to stdout in kubernetes. Most tools can hook into that. Stdout logs are wirtten on the node the pod is running on in /var/log. Fluentd for example can be configured to scrape those.